# I need to get the TV field of the child resource

Tags: php, modx, modx-revolution

To get the parent TV field, I use the following syntax `[[*ceo_comment]]` (which is logical). After the information I found, I came to the conclusion that it might be logical to use the following syntax:

```
`[[pdoMenu?
&parents=`[[*id]]`
&tpl=`@INLINE
[[*ceo_comment]]
`
&where=`{"id:IN":[5,6]}`
&includeContent=`1`
&tvPrefix=`tv.`
]]`
```

But when I run this code, I still get the parent resource.
[5, 6] are the ids of child resources that have different language contexts (Spanish, English).

I think that the problem can be solved in an elementary way. Thank you in advance for your answers.